# keyword "go" in golang, whether go is a atomic operation?

Tags: go

in go programing, we always create a go routine like

```
go func(){}
```

i want to know whether keyword "go" is an atomic operation, what if create a go routine fail by this operation.

can i monitor a new go routine created success or not?

Or maybe this keyword "go" create a routine that will never fail.

Comment: Creating goroutines doesn't fail, just like calling functions doesn't fail (except in ways you can't handle anyway, like running out of memory). I don't know what you mean by atomic in this context.

Comment: Yes, the word “atomic” makes no sense here, but calling a goroutine is roughly the same as calling any function.

Comment: What do you think "atomic" means?  `go` doesn't change any value, so it's not even in the realm of things that can be atomic or not. This is a category error at least.

Comment: `go` is not an operation at all. It indicates that the function call that follows the keyword is to be started in a new goroutine. As others have said, "atomic" doesn't apply; only data operations can be or not be atomic, and a function call is not a data operation. `go` cannot fail unless it fails to allocate memory, which is an error that cannot be handled (forced crash).

Answer (score 2):

The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements) says nothing about failure to create the goroutine or invoke the function, so behavior at this point is up to the implementation and **there is no defined way to determine success or failure**.

The kinds of errors you would encounter on goroutine creation will be fatal errors (likely due to resource exhaustion), not something that can be caught and handled gracefully. This is similar to the kinds of errors you would encounter on invoking a function.